# How can I display a sheet in another sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to  display data from another sheet, but I want it to be the original sheet, not referenced data.
For example, I want to show a graph from sheet 1 in sheet 2 and 3.

Comment: Adi, what you're describing is highly likely an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should change your question to ask what you need, not how you need it.

Answer (score -2):

You need to hold Ctrl key and group the worksheets. Please follow the below link.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Enter-data-in-multiple-worksheets-at-the-same-time-6223d385-4c75-4dff-9881-67d17972a6c9

Comment: this way you can create the same data / chart on multiple sheets at the same time, but those won't be the "same", changing one of them won't change the others in the other sheets as requested in the question.